# How to redirect to custom login page in spring security configurations?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using Spring security configurations for login authentication in order to check for the valid credentials. How can I redirect the application to my custom login page. I tried to implement form-login as shown below, but it did not work for me, Please help me to resolve this.

```
        <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
          xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


            <http auto-config='true'>
              <intercept-url pattern="/secured/*" access="ROLE_USER" />      
              <form-login
                 login-page='/login'
                 default-target-url="/home"
                 authentication-failure-url="/error" /> 
              <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
            </http>

            <authentication-manager>
              <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
            </authentication-manager>   

        </beans:beans>
```

In the above code, login, logout, error and home are my custom pages.
  Following is my controller code.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dashboard(){
        System.out.println("Dashboard method of Login Controller");     
        return "dashboard";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLoginForm(){
        System.out.println("Login method of Login Controller");
        return "login";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLogoutForm(){
        System.out.println("Logout method of Login Controller");
        return "logout";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/error", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginAgain(){
    //  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Login");
        System.out.println("error method of Login Controller");
        return "error";

    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/secured/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)    
    public String getData(ModelMap model){

        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        System.out.println("Returned .... "+principal);   
        System.out.println("Returned object name is :: "+principal.toString());


        model.addAttribute("username", "John");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to the secured page");
        return "home";


      }
```

Following is the login page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Aventyn&reg;| Login</title>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />' >
        <link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/loginCSS.css" />'>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form action="http://localhost:8080/LoginMavenSpringMVC/secured/test" method="get">
            <div class="row margin_Div">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h2 class="panel-title text-center"><strong>Login Page</strong></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">  
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                                    <b>Login Id:</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">*</span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="LoginId" name="UserName">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                                    <b>Password:</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">*</span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password" name="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                    <button class="form-control btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <p>${SucessMsg}</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
            </form>
            </div>


    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value=" /resources/js/jquery.min.js"/>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=' <spring:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>'></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `login-page='/login'` do u have request to handle `/login`?? If no write a request mapping to handle `/login` or for just `/` which will return to login page

Comment: I have the mapping handler. Here what exactly the problem is, I am redirecting to the same login page several times.

Comment: i think everything is correct...`return login` should return to  login page...is your viewResolver working fine?

Comment: Please show your login form view

Comment: Ya view resolver is also working fine. If I add the above form-login in my xml file, its rendering to my login page again and again. So not able to proceed to other pages. So I have commented the form-login attribute in xml file. So it is rendering to default login page of spring security.